# Firebase Cloud Functions deploy error javascript

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm trying to deploy my cloud function firebase CLI, but there is an issue with my functions. I haven't changed any of my firebase cloud function settings. When I try to run `firebase deploy --only` functions, I get the following error:

> npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no
>   such file or directory, open
>   'F:\react\Fullstack-Hoffyevents-react-redux\event\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\wasif\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-11-07T14_41_19_766Z-debug.log
>
> Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero
>   exit code4294963238

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue on windows users

Go to your function folder and open `firebase.json` file

inside you will see something like this

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

change `$RESOURCE_DIR`  with `%RESOURCE_DIR%` and that should work in your next deploy

you should have something like this

```
"functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run build"
    ]
  }
```